# Installing SVN on OS X Lion Server

Tags: osx-lion, svn-server

Can SVN or git be set up on an OS X Lion Server?

How does Lion server work along with other services outside its control?

If I wanted to install WordPress, or MAMP or SVN, how would it be done on OS X Lion Server?

Comment: If you install Xcode (for manually building things), you can pretty much install anything. SVN and git are no problem at all. WordPress hosting is also not a problem.

Comment: Thanks, can it be setup without xcode? I dont want to use it as my dev computer, just a server. I dont want to waste the 3ish gigs on xcode just for svn though.

Comment: Well, that's with the newest builds in mind. You can install [precompiled binaries as well](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/). Same goes [for Git](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) (here, the Snow Leopard version should work).

Comment: Thanks. So I can install mamp, svn everything as usual on a system running lion server?

Comment: I believe so, but SVN ang git clients are not really a big deal. I don't run Lion Server and I don't know how MAMP would interfere though. If you have MAMP you can probably just turn off the Lion Server features.

Comment: Should not be a problem at all. If you don't want to install everything manually, you can use MacPorts.

Comment: thing is I ran the svnadmin create command and it worked, so is SVN installed by default then?

Comment: subversion packages are included by default with the os.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SVN and MAMP is possible in osx lion. you will get the binaries for installing subversion from [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) and for installing MAMP from [here](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/). But my opinion is installing [Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) rather than SVN in OSX,as it is more secure.